# Route in Swagger Missing Lock Icon

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using ASP.NET using C# targeting .NET 8 and when I'm in development mode I am using Swagger UI.

I implemented a custom authentication workflow where I have middleware that checks if a DatabaseAuthenticationAttribute is present and if so then assert a Bearer token which is an API key.

Then in my Program.cs when I call AddSwaggerGen, I specify the SwaggerDoc, AddSecurityDefinition, AddSecurityRequirement, and specify an OperationFilter which is a custom class:

```c#
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(swaggerGenOptions =>
{
    swaggerGenOptions.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "-redacted-", Version = "v1" });
    swaggerGenOptions.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = "Please enter the token as 'Bearer {token}'",
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    swaggerGenOptions.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            Array.Empty<string>()
        }
    });
    swaggerGenOptions.OperationFilter<DatabaseAuthOperationFilter>();
});
```

For completeness, this is what my DatabaseAuthOperationFilter and DatabaseAuthenticationAttribute classes look like:

```c#
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class DatabaseAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute
{
}
public class DatabaseAuthOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var hasAttribute = (
                context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType != null
                && context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DatabaseAuthenticationAttribute>().Any()
            )
            || context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DatabaseAuthenticationAttribute>().Any();

        if (hasAttribute)
        {
            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
            {
                new() {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            },
                            Name = "Authorization",
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                            Scheme = "Bearer"
                        },
                        Array.Empty<string>()
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug my application and setup a breakpoint on `if (hasAttribute)` it is true for the endpoint I'm wanting to add the lock icon to, but when open /swagger/index.html it has the unlock icon.

Is there a step that I'm missing here?